# Change fullCalendar option (i.e. selectable) after click a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, calendar, fullcalendar

I have a small problem with fullCalender.js. I am trying to change an option of the calendar after click a button, but it´s not working.

That is my js:

```
var calendar = $('#calendar');

calendar.fullCalendar({
    header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },

    defaultView: 'month',
    selectable: true
});

$('#but').on(click, function(e) {
    calendar.fullCalendar('selectable', false);
});
```

And my html

```
<div id='calendar'></div>

<button id='but'>
Not selectable
</button>
```

Here the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/CYnJY/874/

What am I doing wrong? 
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change this `$('#but').on(click, function(e) {` to `$('#but').on('click', function(e) {`

Also use `calendar.fullCalendar( 'destroy' )` to destroy calendar and create a new calendar.

```
 $('#but').on('click', function(e) {
   calendar.fullCalendar( 'destroy' )
   calendar.fullCalendar({
    header: {
      left: 'prev,next today',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay'
    },

    defaultView: 'month',
    selectable: false
 });
});
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/k4dhm3yL/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!

Comment: @David Please accepet as answer if it helped